# question about getting value from class

Tags: c++

consider  following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass{
  int a;
  public:
    MyClass(int j) {a = j;}
    int geta(void) {return a;}
};

int main(void)
{
  MyClass ob = 99;              

  cout << ob.geta();
}
```

output of this code is 99
my question is following   statement   MyClass ob    is declare object  of class  MyClass and  is  allowed such kind of declaration that object is equal some number?maybe more specific declaration would be MyClass ob(99)  what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

You provided constructor taking an int. Without `explicit` keyword it can be called implicitly - like here. If you would write `MyClass ob(99)`, you would call this constructor explicitely. There is no difference until you declare constructor as `explicit`. You would get compilation error when trying to assign an int to an object with explicit constructor.

**EDIT**: I checked - it is really using copy constructor too, as David and Alien01 said. It is just Visual Studio that doesn't follow the standard.

Comment: Initialization like `MyClass ob = 99;` means that the copy constructor must be available (e.g error if it is private), but it doesn't mean that the copy constructor has to be called (can be optimized away).

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating an object like

```
MyClass ob =99 ;
```

You are basically calling constructor of the class.

Same holds good when object is created as

```
MyClass ob(99);
```

In this case also ,constructor of class is called.

Comment: No, he's not calling copy constructor. Add `MyClass(const MyClass& asdf):a(asdf.a){cout << "cc call" << endl;}` to his code. "cc call" will not be printed.

Comment: @x13n you are right , if I do like this  MyClass obj(99);    MyClass ob = obj;    then copy constructor will be called

Comment: @x13n: You are wrong and that @Alien01 was right in the first place. The language specifies that `MyClass ob = 99` is equivalent to `MyClass ob( MyClass(99) )`. That is, the compiler creates a temporary with the implicit constructor and *then* copies it to the real object. The effect that you are seeing (lack of output from your copy constructor) is due to an optimization, where the compiler can create the temporary in the same place as the resulting object and thus elide the copy. To verify it, declare the copy constructor private and you will get an access error in the code.

Comment: I tried declaring copy constructor as private and I did not get any error. It compiled fine

Comment: `class test { test( test const & ) {} public: test(int) {} }; int main() { test t = 99; }` is incorrect and should trigger a compilation error as the constructor is `private` at the place of call. If it does not fail, it might be an issue with the compiler not adhering to the current standard (what compiler are you using?). I have provided this and another test to verify this point in an answer below.

Comment: Here is the code that I am using without any compilation  errors #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass{
  int a;
public:
    MyClass(int j) {a = j;}
 
    int geta(void) {return a;}
private:
MyClass(const MyClass &obj){cout << "myclass"<<endl;}
};

int main(void)
{
  MyClass obj =99;
  cout << obj.geta();
}

Answer (score 2):

This is the interesting part:

```
    MyClass(int j) {a = j;}
```

By default, a constructor with a single argument is implicit, which means the compiler automatically calls it wherever you want to assign an `int` where a `MyClass` is expected.

If you don't want this behaviour for your class, simply change the constructor to

```
    explicit MyClass(int j) {a = j;}
```

And the behaviour is gone, now you need to explicitly (hence the keyword) call the constructor every time. Note that the `explicit` keyword should only appear in the declaration in the class body, but not in an implementation outside of the body.

P.S.: This is, for example, how `const char*` automatically becomes a `std::string` when the latter is expected.

Comment: +1 as the clearest answer so far. It would be worth pointing out that most single-arguments constructors should be declared explicit, as implicit conversion is rarely (if ever) needed and can cause a lot of a trouble when it kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer has already been provided by others, including @x13n. I will try to provide a little more detailed explanation of what the code really means.

The syntax `MyObject ob = anotherMyObject;` is equivalent to `MyObject obj( anotherMyObject );`. The meaning is *copy construct `ob` from the object `anotherMyObject`*. The compiler will always match `MyObject ob = ...;` with a call to the copy constructor (usually `MyObject( MyObject const &)`, but can also be `MyObject( MyObject& )` if the user declares it as so).

In your particular code, the right hand side is not a `MyObject`, so it cannot be passed as an argument to the copy constructor and the compiler will try to convert that rhs into something that can be used with the copy constructor of `MyObject` applying the general rules. In your case, there is an implicit constructor that takes an `int` argument, and that can be used to create a temporary `MyObject`, so the compiler rewrites your code to be:

```
MyObject ob( MyObject( 99 ) );
//              ^^^  temporary created by the compiler to match the copy constructor
```

Note that this is not the same as `MyObject ob(99)`, but a combination of the `int` and copy constructors, even if the overall effect is similar. If the constructor taking an integer was declared `explicit`, then the compiler could not use it to provide the conversion and the code would fail to compile.

In a comment to another answer @x13n points out that this is not a call to the copy constructor, as if you add a trace to that constructor, the trace will not be generated. That is a completely different issue, where the compiler is able to optimize away the copy by creating the temporary in exactly the same address that `ob` takes. There are two ways that this can be verified, both dependent on the fact that while the compiler can elide the copy it must adhere to the same restrictions. So we can make `MyObject ob( MyObject(99) )` invalid in two ways, either disabling access to the copy constructor, or disabling the call to the constructor with a temporary:

```
class test1 {
   test1( test1 const & ) {} // make the copy constructor private
public:
   test1( int ) {}
};
class test2 {
public:
   test2( test2 & ) {} // make the copy constructor take a non-const reference 
                       // i.e. disable the use of temporaries
   test2( int ) {}
};
int main() {
   test1 t1 = 99; // copy constructor is private in this context
   test2 t2 = 99; // g++: no matching function call to test2::test2(test2)
                  // diagnostics will differ with other compilers
}
```